# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphics'

Tags: python, graphics

When running this module on my home pc I got this error message. I made this in class today as it was what we were going over. trying to get some more practice on this stuff. Is my python missing a file or something? I am using shell 3.6.3 Thanks!

error message displays on shell:

```
from graphics import * 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphics'
```

module I made in class today:

```
from graphics import *

def main ():
    window = GraphWin ('Mikes Circle Graph Window', 800,600)
    #window.setBackground ('blue')
    circle1 = Circle(Point(250,380), 50)
    circle1.draw (window)
    circle1.setFill ('yellow')

    #p1 = Point (50,50) #step 3
    #p2 = Point (500,500)
    #p1.draw (window) #step 4
    #p2.draw (window)


    #line = Line (Point(50,50), Point(500,500))
    #line.draw (window)
    #line.setFill ('blue')

    triangle = Polygon (Point(40,340), Point(260,80))
    triangle.setFill ('saddle brown')
    triangle.draw (window)
    #input('Enter Something')
    #triangle.move(point(500,50))

    rectangle1 = Rectangle(Point(20,80), Point(560,80))
    rectangle1.draw (window)
    rectangle1.setFill ('blue')

main ()
```

Comment: Is the graphic package installed? run pip install graphics in the shell

Comment: Wasnt not installed, oddly as it was, and I had a very interesting time finding the file. I got it working though thank you! <0